How To Upgrade An Android App From Years Ago From Gradle 8
I have a medical-focused application that finished development back in 2018. Now, (because of upgrades to the mini-pc it is running on) the app isn't working as intended.
The changes I would like to make seem simple, however when I download the latest version of Android studio and download all their suggested dependencies, every single file breaks.
Is it possible to edit the project using older versions of gradle to avoid these issues? Or is there some other process to seamlessly upgrade the app?
My concern is that, in choosing the latter option above, the vast majority of the methods called/overwritten in the upgrade itself will be deprecated, forcing a total redevelopment (rather than literally changing one value from 100 to 50).
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

As you can see by the answers you have multiple options. Which one to choose depends on details you haven't included in your post like what Android version was running in the old and now on the new system as well as the Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin version the app was developed with. Last but not least the targetSDK of the development project would be good to know.

You could instead download old Android Studio version from here , check publication date to choose right version, without change your gradle level project


when I download the latest version of Android studio

You might not want to do that.

and download all their suggested dependencies

You almost certainly do not want to do that.

Is it possible to edit the project using older versions of gradle to avoid these issues?

The latest version of Android Studio and other IDEs might not be happy with a six-year-old version of Gradle, but you can build the app from the command line if needed.
Also, upgrading Gradle itself does not require you to update the dependencies. Your app might build and run fine from within Android Studio with an upgraded Gradle but your current dependencies. However, it is possible that tool changes will either screw up the build or the results.

Or is there some other process to seamlessly upgrade the app?

Not really.

rather than literally changing one value from 100 to 50

If nothing else, use a text editor, then build the app from the command line.
